# How to Delete an entry from MapFile in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Is there any solution to delete an entry from MapFile in Hadoop. I could able to read and write entries to a MapFile, but i am totally unaware of deleting or updating an entry from it. Is there any good solution for the same ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hdfs is basically supports data warehousing facilities. You can not modify existing content of any hdfs file, at most you can append new content at bottom of fine.

You can refer [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104444/updating-a-hadoop-hdfs-file)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose file contain below 2 lines
hi hello world
this is fine
Now in mapper write logic string which contains "hello" , and pass it to reducer phase.
now the reducer output will contain only "hi hello world"
If you want any other than please specify with short use case.